# RewriteRule in htaccess in subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite

Windows server, running Apache. In my Apache conf, I have `AllowOverride None` for the root of a site and then I have a subdirectory set to `AllowOverride All`:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/safe/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

However, when I try to set up a rewrite rule in the subdirectory's `.htaccess` file, nothing happens, I just get a 404 page not found error. Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) /blah?test=$1 [R=302,NC,NE,L]
```

Rewriting URLs are working fine from the root via the Apache conf. I don't understand why the rule is ignored. I don't want to do the URL re-writing within the conf because for this case I may need to be changing the redirects constantly and don't want to reload the server every time a change is made. I also don't want to affect server performance by enabling `.htaccess` files site-wide, just in the subdirectory I need it.

Comment: Turn on the RewriteLog (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog). This should at least give you a hint what mod_rewrite is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of Directory & Location tags in Apache configuration, they have really differents meaning. Directory works on filesystem & location on URIs.

If you're talking about an URL like this: http://example.com/safe/index.html you should do like this:

```
<Location /safe>
    AllowOverride All
</Location>
```

Comment: The `AllowOverride` directive is only permitted in `<Directory>` sections, not `<Location>` sections. `AllowOverride` applies to filesystem paths, not URLs.